# How do I fix this YouTube API searching error and get my code to work?

Tags: python, youtube

```
youtube = build('youtube',"v3", developerKey=youtube_api_key,static_discovery=False)
```

This is not working or returning anything and causes this error:

> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 316, in build
> raise e
> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 287, in build
> content = _retrieve_discovery_doc(
> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 422, in
> _retrieve_discovery_doc
> resp, content = req.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/home/runner/VigorousOutlandishSandbox/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https‍://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest?key=AIzaSyATSKzJcIRFMWCd0dHt5qzzrEmoVQtjuuA returned "YouTube Data API v3 has not been used in project 747787096555 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
> https‍://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=747787096555 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developers console API activation', 'url': 'https‍://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=747787096555'}]}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'SERVICE_DISABLED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'youtube.googleapis.com', 'consumer': 'projects/747787096555'}}]">
> 

Removing this `static_discovery=False` just made a new error about how the name and version and or API key/name was not recognised and please help...

Comment: This part of the error message seems like a good explanation: ` "YouTube Data API v3 has not been used in project 747787096555 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
https‍://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=747787096555 then retry`. It seems like you need to activate the api before you can use it, so try that solution.